# Sistema para medir distância entre 2 locais no meu website

Tags: google-maps, maps

Bom dia,

Estou a fazer um site onde os utilizadores precisam calcular a distância entre 2 locais.
Alguém sabe como ou onde posso usar um sistema que me permita fazer isso no meu website?

Comment: Isso em qual a linguagem?

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Uma das opções é utilizar a `API do Google Maps`. Nela retorna a distancia entre dois endereços e o tempo médio que leva entre os dois pontos.

#### Ex:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=99010030&destinations=99064090&mode=driving&language=pt-BR&sensor=false
```

#### Response:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "São Cristovao, Passo Fundo - RS, 99064-090, Brasil" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Vila Popular, Passo Fundo - RS, 99010-030, Brasil" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "4,7 km",
                  "value" : 4656
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "11 minutos",
                  "value" : 652
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

#### Segue um tutorial bacana que encontrei:

http://cbsa.com.br/post/distancia-entre-cidades---google-maps-javascript-api-v3.aspx